# Is it legal to lock a minor inside the house?

Tags: united-kingdom

My son is 15 and has autism/adhd.  Sometimes we have to lock the doors to prevent him leaving as his behaviour can be unacceptable in the community. Is this legal?  And when does it become illegal (false imprisonment presumably) - at age 16 or 18?

Comment: I would stress that this site is not going to be able to answer your question definitively.  If I were you I would seek information from a support group for parents of autistic children and from the medical people who direct your son's care.  For legal advice that answers this question, you will need to ask, and probably pay, a lawyer, who will take into account the specific effects of your son's condition and nature of his unacceptable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are locking him inside the house with a responsible adult, rather than locking him in his room alone for a long period of time. The latter would probably be considered neglect or abuse. There is no hard law on exactly what measures parents may take so any case would have to be considered on its merits.

Legally [any person under 18](https://www.nspcc.org.uk/preventing-abuse/child-protection-system/legal-definition-child-rights-law/legal-definitions/) is considered to be a child. As parents [you are responsible](https://www.gov.uk/parental-rights-responsibilities) for keeping your child safe, educated, disciplined etc, so the answer to the second part of your question is "On his 18th birthday".

If you believe that your son would present a danger to himself or others after age 18 then you should [speak to a mental health professional](https://www.mind.org.uk/information-support/legal-rights/sectioning/family-members/).

If you are concerned that your son may not have the mental capacity to take on adult responsibilities then you can ask to be [made a deputy for him](https://www.gov.uk/become-deputy) (England and Wales) or get a [guardianship order](https://www.publicguardian-scotland.gov.uk/guardianship-orders) (Scotland). This can start once he is 16, as 16 year old children do have [some rights](https://fullfact.org/law/legal-age-limits/) to conduct their own affairs.